# How do I update offline Electrum wallet after receiving payment with Online seedless wallet?

Tags: wallet, electrum

How do I update offline Electrum wallet after receiving payment with Online seedless wallet?

The guide at: http://electrum.org/tutorials.html#offline-mpk does not say. It only says how to make payments from the offline wallet but not how to receive money to it. I can receive payments to my online seedless wallet, but I don't know how to transfer that to the seeded offline wallet.

Thanks.

P.S. In case some Electrum dev read this there is also an outdated instruction: [Offline PC] Go to Settings -> Import/Export and copy your "Master Public Key" and put it in a text file on your USB-Key. >>> This is now Wallet -> Master Public Key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a seedless wallet the coins received there will need to be signed from the offline computer to be able to spend them. History will be showed in your online PC.

Thanks for pointing out the outdated info.

UPDATE:

You don't need the offline wallet to know how much coins it has, only the online needs that. When you make a payment from the online seedless wallet it knows how much it owns, so the client will spit out the unsigned transaction that needs to be transferred to the offline wallet (with a USB stick or webcam) for it to sign it and then transfer it again to the online PC in order to broadcast it from Electrum.

Comment: To add, if you are using a lot of addresses it might be that the offline wallet has not yet generated those other addresses. In that scenario I imagine you will have to manually generate the addresses using the console command: `wallet.accounts[0].create_new_address(0)` or `wallet.accounts[0].create_new_address(1)` for change addresses. Alternatively you can increase the gap limit `wallet.storage.put('gap_limit', 100)`

Comment: I think this is not needed as the client now uses deterministic signatures. But would be needed if you are generating the addresses trough a script for an online store or something similar.

Comment: the private key has to be there in the offline wallet for it to sign a transaction: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=344115.0